# How to limit Objects on a role basis with Parse.com?

Tags: parsing, acl, parse-platform

Take this example. I have three classes:

```
Role
User
Notes
```

I have this user:

```
id: G3CRqk1vif
username: john
```

And I have this role:

```
id: cKxExXWXFS
name: cia
```

Now, I create a super secret note object:

```
note: Obama is alive!
acl: {"cKxExXWXFS":{"read":true,"write":true}}
```

As you probably already have spotted, the note is saved with the acl of the CIA role. However, if I add user "john" as a relation to the "cia" role, he still can not read the note. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: The situation you describe should work, one thing I would try is to log off and back on as "john" in case his role membership is cached and hasn't refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

The Parse docs say to use this as the ACL instead.

```
{"role:cia" : {"read":true,"write":true}}
```